# How to stop ObjectAnimator in android?

Tags: android, objectanimator

I am using object animator to create a blink effect for my buttons. Everything works fine. Except that I couldnt stop the animation. Is it a bug or am I missing somthing. I have the following methods.

```
   public void manageBlinkEffect(View view){
    objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(view, "backgroundColor", Color.GRAY, Color.YELLOW);
    objectAnimator.setDuration(1000);
    objectAnimator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
    objectAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
    objectAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    objectAnimator.start();
}

public void stopBlinkEffect(View view){
    objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(view, "backgroundColor", Color.GRAY, Color.YELLOW);
    objectAnimator.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a new `object` of `ObjectAnimator` to stop the animation which is started by different `ObjectAnimator`.

It should be like this

```
    ObjectAnimator objectAnimator;

    public void manageBlinkEffect(View view){
        objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(view, "backgroundColor", Color.GRAY, Color.YELLOW)
        objectAnimator.setDuration(1000);
        objectAnimator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
        objectAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        objectAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        objectAnimator.start();
    }

    public void stopBlinkEffect(View view){
        objectAnimator.cancel();
    }
```

Comment: But if i do it like this, I am running into `NullPointerExceptionError`

Comment: @cantona_7 make sure `objectAnimator` is first `instantiated` before you are canceling the animation. So basically you have to first call `manageBlinkEffect ` method to `instantiate` `objectAnimator`, then you should call `stopBlinkEffect ` method.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thanks! 2 extra cents, what i missed: creating an animator _on_ an objects doesn't mean that the target object registers the animation in any sense. Therefor i must make sure that the objectAnimator i created is "remembered" somehow, so that i can stop it later.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the **source code**,The `ObjectAnimator.ofInt(view, "backgroundColor", Color.GRAY, Color.YELLOW);` return new object every time.

you should :

```
    public void manageBlinkEffect(View view){
    objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(view, "backgroundColor", 
    Color.GRAY, Color.YELLOW);
    objectAnimator.setDuration(1000);
    objectAnimator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
    objectAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
    objectAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    objectAnimator.start();
}

public void stopBlinkEffect(View view){
    objectAnimator.cancel();
}
```